# Attempting to add a class attribute to input element on django form.

Tags: django, forms, styles

I am trying to add a class attribute to some input elements on my Django form but I'm not sure how to do it specifically. Currently I just have a `placeholder` attribute, and I'd like to start adding classes/id's so that I can style the form. I have two questions. The first one is how would I go about adding a class/id attribute to the existing placeholder attribute(s) in the following code:

forms.py

```
class EditUserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Motto'}),
            'city': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'City'}),
            'website': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Website/Brand'}),
            'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Phone Number'}),
            }
```

and secondly, after I do this would I need to then makemigrations/migrate? From my understanding you need to migrate whenever a database level change has been made, but I'm not sure what that means entirely.

Any insight is always greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: You are not making a database level change when modifying a form definition, so no migrations are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to add a class to your widgets simply declare it the same way as you did it for placeholder attr. For example...

```
widgets = {
            'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'my_class', 'placeholder': 'Motto'},)
           }
```

Second, you should perform makemigrations/migrate whenever you change your models. In order to adjust your database tables to the new models. Read Django docs for the details.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to add classes in `dict` notation. I tried  `attrs=dict(class='my_class')` but this obviously did not work, since Django (i.e. Python) was expecting a class declaration after `class`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Widget Tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/). With help of this you can add classes to your input and edit other attribute also. Here is good [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/12/04/package-of-the-week-django-widget-tweaks.html).

Answer (score 0):

Below I have changed your form. For your second question `Do you need to call makemigration?` Answer is no. You only need to call makemigration and migrate, when you make any changes in your models.py, for views.py or forms.py etc. You do not need.

```
class EditUserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'

    widgets = {
        'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'#add class name','placeholder': 'Motto'}),
        'city': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'#add class name','placeholder': 'City'}),
        'website': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'#add class name','placeholder': 'Website/Brand'}),
        'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'#add class name','placeholder': 'Phone Number'}),
        }
```

Note: You also don't need to add class name, unless you have specific requirement. If you  want to add class name for css, then you can simply write `id_description` , `id_city`, You can check your id in browser developers tool.